# isEnabled for separators with simpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, cursor, adapter, simplecursoradapter

I have a listview that is populated with a simplecursoradapter that I overrode. I have a query that returns a cursor that is a bunch of items and their separators in the proper order that I need them displayed in. I have everything displaying correctly, but I would like the separators to not be clickable. I am trying to figure out how to override the isEnabled() method so that it returns false for my separators. **My question is how do I know the position of my items or what can I compare the int that is passed to this method with in order to know if it is a separator?** I thought maybe the _id column of the cursor, but because I took data from two different columns for items and categories (my separators) the _id's are jumbled, and sometimes have duplicate numbers. Also, will this cause a problem for me when the rows are drawn? Will I end up getting rows draw in places where the rows have same _ids instead of the row I expect? I tried longer lists to see if this would be the case while scrolling but I did not have an issue so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the int passed in the `isEnabled()` method is the row position of the list for which you need to specify whether it is a separator or not.

> My question is how do I know the
>   position of my items

you can use [moveToPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToPosition%28int%29) to determine which row of the database does this position refer to ?

> what can I compare the int that is
>   passed to this method with in order to
>   know if it is a separator?

It completely depends on how you query the database and determine which rows are separators

> Also, will this cause a problem for me
>   when the rows are drawn? Will I end up
>   getting rows draw in places where the
>   rows have same _ids instead of the row
>   I expect?

NO

Comment: Thanks, It seems to be working correctly now. So I was under the impression that the _id column that was required by cursorAdapters would be used to map the listview rows to my cursor rows. Does the cursor automatically create its own row id's? I'm just interested in how this is working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are actually no row ids which the cursor creates. When you make a DB query there is an option to specify the sort order (if null specified then some default value is applied). The rows are inserted in the cursor in this manner